# determine ideal number of workers and EC2 sizing for master

Tags: locust

I have a requirement to use locust to simulate 20,000 (and higher) users in a 10 minute test window.

the locustfile is a tasksquence of 9 API calls.  I am trying to determine the ideal number of workers, and how many workers should be attached to an EC2 on AWS.  My testing shows with 20 workers, on two EC2 instance, the CPU load is minimal.  the master however suffers big time.  a 4 CPU 16 GB RAM system as the master ends up thrashing to the point that the workers start printing messages like this:

```
[2020-06-12 19:10:37,312] ip-172-31-10-171.us-east-2.compute.internal/INFO/locust.util.exception_handler: Retry failed after 3 times.
[2020-06-12 19:10:37,312] ip-172-31-10-171.us-east-2.compute.internal/ERROR/locust.runners: RPCError found when sending heartbeat: ZMQ sent failure
[2020-06-12 19:10:37,312] ip-172-31-10-171.us-east-2.compute.internal/INFO/locust.runners: Reset connection to master
```

the master seems memory exhausted as each locust master process has grown to 12GB virtual RAM.  ok - so the EC2 has a problem.  But if I need to test 20,000 users, is there a machine big enough on the planet to handle this?  or do i need to take a different approach and if so, what is the recommended direction?

Comment: Are you doing any kind of special processing on the master? 20000 users shouldnt be an issue (unless we have a bug). If you’re at super high throughput then maybe you could get some issues..

Comment: I am doing some extra stats gathering.  I guess I could remove that and test again.

Comment: the extra processing is to get a data point on response time for each of the tasks, for each user.

Comment: But how is it implemented? if it does something performance intensive (like maintain a list of response times for every request ever made) then it could be part of the problem, if not then the problem is probably something unrelated...

Comment: yeah - basically that is what it does.  I have narrowed it down to one task, which is to download an mp3 from cloudfront.  I think what is happening is we exhausting the network connection causing it to take longer and longer.  However, this is an essential part of the testing we need to conduct.  As the network connection is exhausted, the rest of the API call times increase.  I changed my code to just put the times per task sequence into the log file as INFO. the files are on average 8MB for the test which should take hundreds of ms from the EC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my specific case, one of the steps is to download a file from CloudFront which is randomly selected in one of the tasks.  This means the more open connections to cloudFront trying to download a file, the more congested the available network becomes.

Because the app client is actually a native app on a mobile and there are a lot of factors affecting the download speed for each mobile, I decided to to switch from a GET request to a HEAD request.  this allows me to test the response time from CloudFront, where the distribution is protected by a Lambda@Edge function which authenticates the user using data from earlier in the test.

Doing this dramatically improved the load test results and doesn't artificially skew the other testing happening as with bandwidth or system resource exhaustion, every other test will be negatively impacted.

Using this approach I successfully executed a 10,000 user test in a ten minute run-time.  I used 4 EC2 T2.xlarge instances with 4 workers per T2.  The 9 tasks in test plan resulted in almost 750,000 URL calls.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the question in the title is: "It depends"

Your post is a little confusing. You say you have 10 master processes? Why?

This problem is most likely not related to the master at all, as it does not care about the size of the downloads (which seems to be the only difference between your test case and most other locust tests)

There are some general tips that might help:

- Switch to FastHttpUser (https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/increase-performance.html)
- Monitor your network usage (if your load gens are already maxing out their bandwidth or CPU then your test is very unrealistic anyway, and adding more users just adds to the noice. In general, start low and work your way up)
- Increase the number of loadgens

In general, the number of users is not an issue for locust, but number of requests per second or bandwidth might be.

Comment: yep - 1 master - 10 workers.  I think I have a workaround.  thanks for the help.

Comment: If you have found a workaround, please post it here. You can even add it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Also, please edit your question so that it makes sense (mainly the part that says "each locust master process (there are 10 of them)"). The point of stackoverflow is not that just you get helped, but others too.